# Electron - throws ERR_FAILED when making requests using Net

Tags: electron

I am using **Electron 8** and making a internet connection check by making a request to api. The connection check was made every 10 second.
If the status was true we will load the external content otherwise will show a local file. The request is failing with **ERR_FAILED** when the application is running for a longer duration maybe for 15 to 20 hours. Also the issue is not happening in all machines, only in some machines. The application is running in windows 10.

Comment: Finally i was able to identify the root cause. The issue was cache. After completely disabling the cache the issue was fixed.

`const { app } = require ("electron");

app.commandLine.appendSwitch ("disable-http-cache");`